# Verifying a Receipt with the App Store

Tags: iphone

Retrieve the receipt data from the transaction’s transactionReceipt property and encode it using base64 encoding.

How can I encode NSData using base64 encoding? Please give the code for that.

***EDIT***

I did it. but now the response is

```
{exception = "java.lang.NullPointerException"; status = 21002;}
```

my recipt verification method is this

```
-(BOOL)verifyReceipt:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSString *recieptString = [transaction.transactionReceipt base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",recieptString);

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]]];

    [request setPostValue:recieptString forKey:@"receipt-data"];
    [request setPostValue:@"95140bdac98d47a2b15e8e5555f55d41" forKey:@"password"];
    [request start];

    NSDictionary* subsInfo = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",subsInfo);

    return subscriptionEnabled;
}
```

Where

```
NSString *recieptString = [transaction.transactionReceipt base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
```

returns me base64 encoded string. 
I also tried

```
NSString *recieptString = [transaction.transactionReceipt base64EncodingWithLineLength:[transaction.transactionReceipt length]];
```

but response is same.

can any one of you let me know where I could be wrong.

Thanks-

Comment: It would be helpful to have some more context.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
+ (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: where did you get the base64 encoding code that works with Apple receipt verifier server? it was working but it is no longer working anymore (current iOS 10.0, base sdk: 8.0)

Comment: sorry.. I POST receipt-data="xxx" whereas I should POST in JSON "{ \"receipt-data\" : \"xxx\"}"

Comment: now it works, but I am still curious where did you get the code.. even Apple's [NSData base64EncodedStringWithOptions] doesn't work, whatever the options is... stupid Apple..

Comment: This above is the core algorithm to convert anything to base64 if you search google you could find this in almost every other language

Answer (score 1):

You need to post your receipt to "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" while testing in the sandbox environment.