# Base64 Decoding in iOS 7+

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7, ios8

I have Encoded text(`NSString`) using `NSData` Class new API which is Added in iOS7.

using this

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```

here is my code

```
NSString *base64EncodedString = [[myText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSLog(@"%@", base64EncodedString);
```

I am looking to decode it

Comment: `m_EncodeText`: please stop

Comment: where have you found `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`?

Comment: @user2159978 it's there in apple docs  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It seems It happens when I use mac os console application target. Or the old version of sdk/mac os target

Answer (score 446, accepted):

## Swift 3+

```
let plainString = "foo"
```

#### Encoding

```
let plainData = plainString.data(using: .utf8)
let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedString()
print(base64String!) // Zm9v
```

#### Decoding

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String!),
   let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8) {
  print(decodedString) // foo
}
```

---

## Swift < 3

```
let plainString = "foo"
```

#### Encoding

```
let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
print(base64String!) // Zm9v
```

#### Decoding

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String!, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(decodedString) // foo
```

---

## Objective-C

```
NSString *plainString = @"foo";
```

#### Encoding

```
NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String); // Zm9v
```

#### Decoding

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", decodedString); // foo
```

---

Comment: I don't think this code is clean. I get the warning : "incompatible pointer types initializing NNSTring with an expression of NSData"

Comment: @drlobo you must have typed base64EncodedDataWithOptions: instead of base64EncodedStringWithOptions:

Comment: Thanks for this. Something I just found: a constant `kNilOptions` is equal to 0 which is arguably more readable than using 0 for options.

Comment: @AdamWaite `kNilOptions` is defined in `MacTypes.h` which is a legacy OSX header, so I don't like using it, since I think that header should be removed from the iOS SDK altogether. Anyway, you have a point in saying that is very readable, so feel free to use it.

Comment: it seems the method base64EncodedStringWithOptions is not url safe base64

Comment: base64 decoding works only if the string length is a multiple of 4. otherwise NSData returns nil.

Comment: this code works well But in my case i get xml response from server which are already in base64 encoded .I have decode that data but when i use this method it returns null. can anybody suggest me tackle this problem ???

Comment: Decoding may not work if there's a new line following the encoded data. See, for example, [Decode base64 data encoded in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31336064).

Comment: if anyone getting a nil try `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters` i had this issue

Comment: I was decoding a JWT token, and learned there were a few more fancy steps to decode it. I used the method `base64decode` from https://github.com/Wstunes/SwiftyJWT after parsing the JWT token at the periods.

Comment: While decoding the base64String I was getting nil for using
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];

So, I used 
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 82):

In case you want to write fallback code, decoding from base64 has been present in iOS since the very beginning by caveat of `NSURL`:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@",
           base64String]];

return [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

Comment: I'm totally impressed with this answer. For years i've been using some ridiculous amount of code to decode a string, and all along there was a 2 line solution.

Comment: This is awesome! Hacky, but awesome :)

Comment: I've never thought is is so easy! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

While decoding the base64String I was getting nil for using:

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
```

So, I used:

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```

And it worked for me.