# 'initWithBase64Encoding' is deprecated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I want to get the data from the string. i am using the following code but it seems to be deprecated.

```
 NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithBase64Encoding:(NSString *)dict];
```

I got the data. But its give me the warning that 'initWithBase64Encoding' is deprecated.
So is there any other method that will return data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base64 Decoding in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use this

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
```

instand of

```
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithBase64Encoding:(NSString *)dict];
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns a data object initialized with the given Base-64 encoded string. (Deprecated in iOS 7.0. You should transition to either `initWithBase64EncodedString:options`: or `initWithBase64EncodedData:options`:.)

Answer (score 1):

Use following

**ENCODE**

```
NSString *myString = @"Developer";
NSData *myData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String);
```

**DECODE:**

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", decodedString);
```