# In-app purchases receipt validation on server and new line characters

Tags: validation, ios7, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I'm currently working on a solution with In-App purchases which validate to our back-end server and I've come across some issue while sending the receipt to our server. When I retrieve it by doing

```
 NSURL *receiptUrl = [bundle appStoreReceiptURL];
            receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];
            NSString *string = [receipt base64EncodedString];
```

the result is something like this (just an excerpt)

```
MIIVOAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIVKTCCFSUCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIE6QYJKoZI\r\n
```

There are these characters **\r\n** which appear quite often dividing this indicate return and new line. Is there any way to convert to a string without these characters? Is it safe to just use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: to remove them or should I assume these characters could appear randomly on the base64 string without the "new line" meaning? If I validate the receipt with these characters it returns 21002 which indicates receipt-data is malformed, but by using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString it validates OK, so my question is if I should be removing these characters by hand or should I convert the receipt somehow?

Comment: It sounds like some issue with your base 64 encoding.

Comment: Apparently iOS7 has some base 64 encoding methods if you don't have to support earlier versions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7