# decode from base64 to UTF8

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

I'm unable to decode below sentence from base64 to UTF8.

> YW5kIHNhbmcgdGhlIHNvbmcgb2YgR29kJ3Mgc2VydmFudCBNb3NlcyBhbmQgb2YgdGhlIExhbWI6IJNHcmVhdCBhbmQgbWFydmVsb3VzIGFyZSB5b3VyIGRlZWRzLCBMb3JkIEdvZCBBbG1pZ2h0eS4gSnVzdCBhbmQgdHJ1ZSBhcmUgeW91ciB3YXlzLCBLaW5nIG9mIHRoZSBuYXRpb25zLiBE

This is the code which i used to decode.

```
NSString *strDecode =  @"YW5kIHNhbmcgdGhlIHNvbmcgb2YgR29kJ3Mgc2VydmFudCBNb3NlcyBhbmQgb2YgdGhlIExhbWI6IJNHcmVhdCBhbmQgbWFydmVsb3VzIGFyZSB5b3VyIGRlZWRzLCBMb3JkIEdvZCBBbG1pZ2h0eS4gSnVzdCBhbmQgdHJ1ZSBhcmUgeW91ciB3YXlzLCBLaW5nIG9mIHRoZSBuYXRpb25zLiBE";

[Base64 initialize];
NSData * data = [Base64 decode:strDecode];

strDecode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"strDecode::::%@",strDecode);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See answer on the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7

Comment: I've already try this one.but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use decoding from here:
 [Base64 Decoding in iOS 7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7)
but use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` as encoding instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` since decoded sequence is not valid as UTF-8 string.