# How to extarct or unzip a json key (from API) uisng xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, zip

This is my zipped `JSON` value from `API` response:

```
"response": {
"Status": 1,
"assetdescription": null,
"lastgatewayreport": "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",
"Msg": "Success"
}
```

This should be like this

```
"response": {
"Status": 1,
"assetdescription": null,
"lastgatewayreport": [
  {
    "assetid": 1359,
    "assetname": "Jimmyy",
    "assetgroupname": null,
    "groupname": "Default",
    "groupid": 938,
    "datetime": "08/12/2016 16:49:29",
    "batt": 45,
    "extsensor": -100000,
    "extsensortype": null,
    "humidity": -100000,
    "temperatur .......
```

That unzip content have `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`

I already tried convert to `NSData` then `JSONObjectWithData` but not working.

How can I unzip that json key in objective c. I am using AFNetworking. Is that possible to unzip those content.

Comment: Looks like `lastgatewayreport` is a base64 gz zipped data. I'm not good at Objective-C, but looks like you need to find a library to decompress "base64  gz". http://www.txtwizard.net/compression

Comment: So actually you need an array of objects as response and you are getting above response from api then you need to contact to server team as i see here ?.

Comment: @vaibhav I have another option to get clear response (without zip content), but I need to know what kind of zip that's it. I think below answer Jon Rose shared correct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is gziped (enter it in here: http://www.txtwizard.net/compression).  After you get the data you have to ungzip it and then run `JSONObjectWithData`. I have had good experience using https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP to gzip and ungzip data.

Comment: Thanks for your share Jon Rose. I am checked with your first txtwizard with my `NSString` with decompress and I got output there. In code I didn't get that. ```- (BOOL)isGzippedData;``` this one return `NO`. 
```NSString *zipString = responseDict[@"lastgatewayreport"];
              NSData *jsonData = [zipString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
BOOL isZipped = [jsonData isGzippedData];```

Comment: Got it from [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991160/convert-base64-gzipped-string-objective-c-or-swift).
```NSData* compressedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:zipString options:0];
              NSData *jsonData = [compressedData gunzippedData];
              NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];```