# Decompress GZip byte array in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, gzip

I'm developing an iOS application using objective-c. In that I'm receiving data from server in gzip byte array format.

Can anyone tell me how to decompress the byte array in desired objective-c format(NSData, NSArray or NSDictionary etc).

Comment: This answer will help you for your gZIP query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991160/convert-base64-gzipped-string-objective-c-or-swift

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP which zips and unzips NSData with good results.

You can use `[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: bytesArray length:length];` to convert from a byte array to NSData.

Comment: But I'm getting response in byte array and not in NSData. How to unzip/decode the byte array?

Comment: What library are using to get data from the server that give you a byte array instead of NSData?