# Decode base64 data encoded in bash

Tags: objective-c, base64

I'm trying to decode some data which I encoded in bash using

```
base64 -in file.txt -out encodedFile.txt
```

Decoding it in bash is no problem.

But when I try to decode it in Objective-C using

```
//fetch encoded data from file system, put it in
//NSData *encoded
NSData *decoded = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedData:encoded withOptions:0];
```

I'm always receiving nil.

**EDIT**

I tried encoding the same file in Objective-C and noticed there is only one small difference:

Encoded in bash:

```
dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qh
```

Encoded in Objective-C:

```
VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qh
```

Only the first character is different.

Comment: Please add a reason for the downvote, so I can adjust the way I ask a question.

Comment: Also see [Base64 Decoding in iOS 7+](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22432808/608639) and Tommy's answer for another way to do it that works on all iOS devices.

Comment: @jww I actually came across that when searching for a solution to my problem. But I only need to support iOS 7 and up, so no problem there. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Apparently there was a newline (`\n`) appended to the end of the file.
Once I removed that, it worked normally.

For those who are interested, I managed to do this in one command using

```
base64 -i file.txt | tr -d '\n' > encodedFile.txt
```