# Loading a previously saved audio file as base64 string

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I record and save an audio file, this works and plays in the app as expected.
After the recording, however, I try to load it so I can pass the audio into a JSON object, but can't open it.

I get the following error:

> ```
> The file “audio.m4a” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined.
> ```

This is call I'm making:

```
do {
     let audioData =  try NSData(contentsOfFile: String(contentsOf: audioURL!))
} catch {
     print error
}
```

Any ideas how I can load the audio data as from the file in base64 encoding?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load audio file contents as a base64 in swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397957/how-to-load-audio-file-contents-as-a-base64-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't explain how do you save your file, so i can only assume (according to file extension), that you are not saving it as base64 string.
Please refer to first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7) question. To check if you save audio file as base64 string correctly.
But still you can use other way. At first load data:

```
let audioData =  try Data(contentsOf: audioURL!)
```

Then convert it to base64 string:

```
let encodedString = audioData.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: I've used parts of code from the question, so @rubyist could better understand of what he should changes in his code.

Comment: Thanks that works. I'm new to Swift so I'm just getting to grips with it,

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using the wrong method. The audio data it is not a string it is a collection of bytes (an array of UInt8). To read your audio data you need to use the Data initializer `Data(contentsOf: audioURL)` and convert this data to base64 string using Data instance method base64EncodedString.

```
if let base64String = try? Data(contentsOf: audioURL).base64EncodedString() {
    print(base64String)
}
```