# Unable to decode base64string to UIImage in iOS swift but working fine in android

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I have this code to convert `UIImage` to `base64EncodedString` and from `base64EncodedString` back to `UIImage` on both iOS and Android app.

The problem is when I convert `UIImage` to `base64EncodedString` and send to my Android device it works,
also when I receive `base64EncodedString` from an Android device to IOS this function `imageFromBase64` will decode it to `UIImage` without issue.
But when converting `UIImage` to `base64EncodedString` in the IOS function and trying to decode it in IOS using this function `imageFromBase64` it will return nil.

I have the below code to convert the image to `base64EncodedString`

```
if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
    let thumb1 = image.resized(withPercentage: 0.3)
    if let imageData = thumb1?.jpeg(.medium) {
        let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        tryEmitMessage(message: strBase64)
    }
}
```

my android example to convert bitmap to `base64EncodedString`

```
public static byte[] bitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
byte[] bm = BitmapUtils.bitmapToByte(bitmap_image);
String strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(bm, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

The bellow function is what is use to decode `base64EncodedString` to `UIImage`

```
func imageFromBase64 (base64:String) -> UIImage {
    let imageData = Data.init(base64Encoded: base64, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    return image!
}

let message = "base64 string"
dataView.uiimage_image = imageFromBase64(base64: message)
```

my android example to convert `base64EncodedString` to bitmap

```
byte[] b = Base64.decode("base64 string", Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0,b.length);
```

Please any idea how to encode and decode base64 images in iOS Swift?

Comment: Encoding: `options: .lineLength64Characters)` and decoding: `options: .init(rawValue: 0)` Might want to test with `.ignoreUnknownCharacters` instead of `init(rawValue: 0)`?

Comment: @Larme it worked with `ignoreUnknownCharacters `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do:

```
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

and

```
let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
```

So you added an option for the encoding, but not for the decoding? Is the  default" decoding working then? No need to specify that there was a perticular option set?

Let's see the doc of [`lineLength64Characters`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/base64encodingoptions/1407872-linelength64characters):

> Set the maximum line length to 64 characters, **after which a line ending is inserted**.

Let's the the doc of available [`Data.Base64DecodingOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/base64decodingoptions), especially [`.ignoreUnknownCharacters`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/base64decodingoptions/1410087-ignoreunknowncharacters):

> Modify the decoding algorithm so **that it ignores unknown non-Base-64 bytes, including line ending characters**.

See?

Use `.ignoreUnknownCharacters` while decoding instead of `.init(rawValue:0)` (which by the way could be simplified with `[]`, or simply not putting the parameter since `[]` is its default value).